# Oracle SQL - min date according to clause

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I need help with folloiwing assigment.
I have following table of communications:

| COMMUNICATION ID | COMMUNICATION TIME | COMMUNICATION STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 636 | 9/3/2021 8:48:49 | new |
| 636 | 10/3/2021 10:47:31 | accepted |
| 636 | 12/3/2021 8:41:42 | new |
| 636 | 12/3/2021 9:43:49 | accepted |

and second table of responses (to communications):

| COMMUNICATION ID | RESPONSE TIME | RESPONSE STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 636 | 10/3/2021 9:30:49 | displayed |
| 636 | 11/3/2021 7:48:49 | realized |
| 636 | 12/3/2021 10:28:49 | displayed |
| 636 | 17/3/2021 11:19:49 | realized |

I need to group communications according to communication id, BUT I need to know also the closest "realization time", that means the time of first realized response after current communication time.

In result, I need something like that:

| COMMUNICATION ID | MAX(COMMUNICATION_TIME) | REALIZED RESPONSE TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 636 | 10/3/2021 10:47:31 | 11/3/2021 7:48:49 |
| 636 | 12/3/2021 9:43:49 | 17/3/2021 11:19:49 |

Would you be so kind and help, what analytical functions (or other steps) should I use?
Status of the communication can be changed, but I consider only time of "realized" responses. There can be more realized responses, but I need only "the closest one" to time of communication.
Each "realized" response shoud have separate "row" in result set, it should "divide" communication.

Thank you very much

Comment: actually you need earliest realized response time?

Comment: yes exactly. but consider, that same communication ID can have two "realizations" , so then I need in final result set two rows (as in example).

Comment: Please clearly explain the logic you want implemented.

Comment: I have a table of communications and second table of responses. I need to get grouped communications, but these communications should be separate also by "realizations" . So not only "grouped" by Communication ID. Because each realization "close" communication, so if same ID will come, it should be visible in results as "different communication". Therefore I put to example these collumn "realized response time", that is taken from "earliest" realized response, but earliest accoding to meaning mentioned above (one communication ID can have multplie realizations in different time).

Comment: Logic: Communication ID 636 has been created. Several response will be created in different times. If realized response is created, communicaiton is "closed" - this is one communicaiton in result set. Another ID 636 came. Again several responses will be created and again, if realized response is created, communication is closed - second record in result set.

Comment: Of couse, there can be different communication IDs, but I hope, this is obvious. It is just example of one communication.

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle 12c, you can `UNION ALL` to concatenate the two tables and then use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT 'c' AS type, id, time, status FROM communications
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'r' AS type, id, time, status FROM responses
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY time
  MEASURES
    new_comms.time AS new_time,
    realized.time AS realized_time
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( new_comms other_comms* realized )
  DEFINE
    new_comms AS (type, status) IN (('c', 'new')),
    other_comms AS (type, status) NOT IN (('c', 'new'),('r', 'realized')),
    realized AS (type, status) IN (('r', 'realized'))
)
```

*Note: this will not allow overlapping communications.*

Or, in earlier versions, you can use `LEAD` with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT id,
       time AS new_time,
       realized_time
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(
           CASE WHEN type = 'r' AND status = 'realized' THEN time END
         ) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
           PARTITION BY id
           ORDER BY time
         ) AS realized_time
  FROM   (
    SELECT 'c' AS type, id, time, status FROM communications
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'r' AS type, id, time, status FROM responses
  ) t
)
WHERE  type = 'c'
AND    status = 'new'
```

*Note: this would allow overlapping communications (but two `new` rows would likely match the same `realized` row in this case).*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE communications ( ID, TIME, STATUS ) AS
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-09' + INTERVAL '08:48:49' HOUR TO SECOND, 'new' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-10' + INTERVAL '10:47:31' HOUR TO SECOND, 'accepted' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-12' + INTERVAL '08:41:42' HOUR TO SECOND, 'new' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-12' + INTERVAL '09:43:49' HOUR TO SECOND, 'accepted' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE responses( ID, TIME, STATUS ) AS
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-10' + INTERVAL '09:30:49' HOUR TO SECOND, 'displayed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-11' + INTERVAL '07:48:49' HOUR TO SECOND, 'realized' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-12' + INTERVAL '10:28:49' HOUR TO SECOND, 'displayed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 636, DATE '2021-03-17' + INTERVAL '11:19:49' HOUR TO SECOND, 'realized' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NEW_TIME | REALIZED_TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 636 | 2021-03-09 08:48:49 | 2021-03-11 07:48:49 |
> | 636 | 2021-03-12 08:41:42 | 2021-03-17 11:19:49 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7817b1e02f2dba9395ead83fd87bdeb)*

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want the maximum communication time per realized response. One way:

```
select
  r.communication_id,
  r.response_time,
  max(c.communication_time)
from responses r
join communications c
  on c.communication_id = r.communication_id
  and c.communication_time < r.response_time 
where r.response_status = 'realized'
group by r.communication_id, r.response_time
order by r.communication_id, r.response_time;
```

Another:

```
select
  r.communication_id,
  r.response_time,
  last_c.communication_time
from responses r
cross apply
(
  select communication_time
  from communications c
  where c.communication_id = r.communication_id
  and c.communication_time < r.response_time 
  order by c.communication_time desc
  fetch first row only
) last_c
where r.response_status = 'realized'
order by r.communication_id, r.response_time;
```